# The method 'toMap' isn't defined for the type 'UserData'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

The problem shows at my sign_in.dart

```
await firebaseFirestore
        .collection("parkingTech")
        .doc(user?.uid)
        .set(userModel.toMap()); //problem
    Fluttertoast.showToast(msg:"Account created Successfully");
```

Heres my code for user.data

```
class UserData {
  late final String uid;
  late final String car;
  late final String name;
  late final String num;

  UserData({required this.uid,required this.car,required this.name,required this.num});
}
```

Can someone help me please

Comment: `UserData` does not have the member method `toMap`, so you have to implement it to de desire functionality.

Comment: @Wilson Toribio is right. If you have the json you can generate such class or write yourself. https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/